# Java Acces resources from inside JAR in multi JAR application

Tags: java

My java application consists of two JARs and resource folder, one of the JARs contain a class inside a somepackage and it needs to load a resource file from resources folder in the root of the application outside the JAR contain this class how can this class load the resource file with getClass().getResource() or other method

```
File Structure

    Main Application 
    -resources
    -jar_1 
    -jar_2 
       -com
          -somepackage
```

Comment: Sounds like you should revisit the structure of your components. If something "inside" needs something from "outside" ... that somehow smells like the outside thing should live inside? (where, technically, I might be possible to resolve your problem; but I have to admit that I am unable to tell you how exactly ;-)

Comment: So is resource file inside of another JAR in resources folder, is that what you are saying or is it just some file in that folder?

Comment: No the resources folder is in the root of the application and not inside any JAR.

Comment: Jägermeister , if it is live inside I would never ask how to access it this rather easy or???? but it can not because the program will be build in complex way that any thing other than JAVA files will inside the  be excluded OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/"+docLocation`);

Comment: João , I will try it.

Comment: I used MyClass.getResourceAsStream("resources/someResource.txt"); it solved the problem.